# Right edge of button's box-shadow cut off when button is right floated

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

My Bootstrap-styled button is the last element at the bottom of the main content container, and I applied `float: right` to it.

When clicking on it, `Bootstrap` applies a `box-shadow` to it. But the right and bottom edges of that shadow are invisible, cut off by the right and bottom corner of the parent container.

How to solve this problem?

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
  Submit
</button>
```

Comment: Please, put clearfix class of button parent element.

Comment: The issue you describe does not normally happen in Bootstrap and is likely caused by some other CSS you are applying. Without the ability to inspect the issue ([mcve]) it is impossible to know what causes it and, therefore, to provide any useful insight.